# При получении значения из списка получаю такое D/Название: com.example.xxxxxxx.Accounts@e2e799b

Tags: java, android, база-данных, запрос, firebase

**Данные загружаю с Firebase**

```
 //Передача в новое Активити
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
           Object obj = list.getAdapter().getItem(position);
           String str = obj.toString();
           Log.d("Название ", str);        
        }
    });
```

Сам адаптер:

```
           //Адаптер для ListView
    private class AccAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Accounts> {
    AccAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_design);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_design, null);
        final Accounts accounts = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(accounts.text_one);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.about)).setText(accounts.text_two);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).setText(accounts.text_three);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам надо у класс Accounts переопределить toString метод и в нём описать что вы хотите получить этот метод вызывая

Comment: Может будет достаточно кастить `list.getAdapter().getItem(position)` к `Accounts`? P.S. переименуйте тип в `Account`, один элемент списка во множественном числе очень режет глаз.